# How to install Ubuntu on XPS 15 Platinum - 2014 version properly

Tags: dell, touchscreen, xps

Just receive a new computer (Dell XPS 15 Platinum - 2014 version).

I want to install Ubuntu on this one but I'm not sure everything can work... Here are some feature I'm afraid it does not work:

- touchscreen
- awesome dell pad
- great battery life (support of various hardware behaviors)
- only one in/out sound plug
- very high resolution (1800p !)

For now I can't test anything: I tried serveral live usb keys but the system never starts. I'm blocked on the logo with every little circle loaded.

Things I notice:

- My computer get hot while I wait at this step
- I can't stop everything just by clicking my shutdown button

Do you know why I can't test ? If Ubuntu has a good support of theses things ?

Thanks !

Comment: Note: Ubuntu 14.04 works out of the box. The main problem is to resize firefox on about:config section. Even the touchscreen is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:
Ubuntu on the Precision M3800 or XPS15 Nov 2013

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2013/11/14/ubuntu-on-the-precision-m3800.aspx

You should just follow standard UEFI install procedures. Best to use 13.10 as it supposedly includes all of sputnik or wait for 12.04.4 in Jan. Very new systems need newest version of Linux/Ubuntu.

Shows install with screen shots for both BIOS & UEFI, so you know which you are using.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot. required for UEFI & grub bug fixes

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: You're totaly out of topic. I tell you the system starts to start (yes I see the logo of ubuntu). I didn't tried to install it, just testing it with USB Live Key. Please read before anwsering :) .

Comment: You have not said what version as only 13.10  may work with the newest systems. And the Dell tech center link discusses issues with XPS15.

Comment: Nop ubuntu 13.04 works with uefi. Uefi problems are before seeing the logo (witch announce the system is loading). What dell link ? :o

Comment: First link in post. It is on m3800 but says it also is for other Dell systems.

Comment: My bad I thougt it was only about the XPS 13. There is a fix for the touchscreen ! I'm going to check bumblebee, Mir and Cubuntu to have a solution for the wrong boot, battery life etc...